# Publish Asp.net with shell32 dll

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-webpages, shell32.dll

I use the following code to get size of a video in seconds. I use the shell32 dll. When I try to publish, the dll is not on the bin folder. Once I publish my project on IIS 7, I get an error ( I suppose it is because that dll is not working ). The code I use is :

```
Type shellAppType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
                Object shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellAppType);
                var folder = (Shell32.Folder)shellAppType.InvokeMember("NameSpace",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shell, new object[] { full_path_video });

                Double totallenght=0.0;
                foreach (FolderItem2 item in folder.Items())
                {
                    if (item.Name == newname)
                    {
                        totallenght = item.ExtendedProperty("System.Media.Duration") / 10000000;
                    }
                }
```

Is there anywthing else to publish my project? I tried adding the dll by "Add reference " option, at my local it works fine, but on server, it just dont.

Comment: Are you trying to publish the solution with 32bit?

Comment: You really don't need to copy that DLL as it is part of every Windows installation... Also it is probably not going to help you - generally all user-related COM objects are not registered (or will not function properly) when running from service context (IIS or any other service) .